# MySql SUM(1) returns the total count of the records in the table

Tags: mysql

I encountered query that looks like this:

`SELECT member_id, prefix, Sum(1) AS Expr1 from .....`

I was puzzled by the `Sum(1)` part. I didn't know what it does. then I tried a simplified query and discovered that the result of `Sum(1)` is equal to the total count of the records in the table **count(*) x 1**.

`Sum(2)` would return **count(*) x 2**

`Sum(3)` would return **count(*) x 3**
etc..

Tried to find such example in the internet with some explanation but couldn't. Sum expression is never a literal number. Can you help me understand this?

Comment: It's a bit like evaluating an expression '1=1'. Every time it evaluates as true (which is always), you get a point, so it's similar to COUNT(0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have used it, the `SUM()` function will sum the value/column input across all records in the table (assuming there is no `WHERE` clause).  In this case, you are summing a constant value of 1 for each record.  Consider the following sample data which might better help you to understand:

```
member_id | prefix | one (constant 1)
1         | A      | 1  \
2         | B      | 1   - SUM(1) = 3 in this case
3         | C      | 1  /
```

It should be intuitive that taking the sum of the `member_id` values would yield 6 as the output.  If we take `SUM(1)` across a table with a total of three records, we would get 3, the number of records.

Comment: Aha, I understand now. The query is used in conjunction with `GROUP BY` - this is why `Sum(1)` is used to add the count of the grouped elements.

Comment: @Hairi Maybe...but even if `GROUP BY` is not used, `SUM` would be applied to every record.  You may think of this as a table level aggregate function.